# Proof by cases using Coq

Tags: logic, coq, theorem-proving

I have a simple theorem that I want to prove using proof by cases. An example is given below.

```
Goal forall a b : Set, a = b \/ a <> b.
Proof
  intros a b.
  ...
```

How would I go about solving this. And, exactly how would I define a proof by cases using the two possible values of an equality (True or False)?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: What version of Coq are you using?  Are you asking for a proof based on the tautology `A \/ ~A`, or do you have in mind an example which assumes your specific disjuntion `a = b \/ a <> b` ?

Answer (score 7):

I am pretty sure that equality of `Set`s is not decidable in Coq. The reasons (to my limited understanding) would be that it is not an inductively-defined set (so, no case analysis for you...), and that it is not a closed set either: everytime you define a new datatype, you create a new family of inhabitants of `Set`. Therefore, the term that proved the goal you show would need to be updated to reflect these new inhabitants.

As @hardmath mentions in his comment, you may prove your goal using `Classical` assumptions (`Axiom classic : forall P:Prop, P \/ ~ P.`).

As @Robin Green mentions in a comment here, you can prove this kind of goal for types that are decidably equal. To this purpose, you may want to get help from the `decide equality` tactic. See: http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/refman/Reference-Manual011.html#@tactic121

Comment: To elaborate on this answer slightly, there are two main ways of proving this result for some type T (where here T is `Set`). If T has a known decidable procedure for equality, then simply use the proof that the procedure is decidable. If it doesn't, one has to resort to classical logic; the default logic of Coq is intuitionistic.

Answer (score 4):

Your question touches an interesting aspect of Coq: the difference between propositions (i.e., members of `Prop`) and booleans (i.e., members of `bool`). Explaining this difference in detail would be somewhat too technical, so I'll just try to focus on your particular example.

Roughly speaking, a `Prop` in Coq is not something that evaluates to either `True` or `False`, like a regular boolean does. Instead, `Prop`s have *inference rules* that can be combined to infer facts. Using those, we can show that a proposition holds, or show that it is contradictory. What makes things subtle is that there is a third possibility, namely that we're not able to either prove or refute the proposition. This happens because Coq is a *constructive logic*. One of the most well-known consequences of this is that the familiar reasoning principle known as the *excluded middle* (`forall P : Prop, P \/ ~ P`) can't be proved in Coq: if you assert that `P \/ ~ P`, this means you're either able to prove `P` or to prove `~ P`. You can't assert this without knowing which one holds.

It turns out that for some propositions, we can show that `P \/ ~ P` holds. For instance, it is not hard to show `forall n m : nat, n = m \/ n <> m`. Following the above remark, this means that for every pair of natural numbers, we are able to produce a proof that they are equal or a proof that they aren't.

On the other hand, if we change `nat` to `Set`, like in your example, then we will never be able to prove the theorem. To see why, consider the `Set` `nat * nat` of pairs of natural numbers. If we were able to prove your theorem, then it would follow that `nat = nat * nat \/ nat <> nat * nat`. Again, by the above remark, this means that we're either able to prove `nat = nat * nat` or `nat <> nat * nat`. However, because there is a bijection between both types, we can't say that it is contradictory to assume `nat = nat * nat`, but because the types are not syntactically equal, it is also OK to assume that they are different. Technically speaking, the validity of the proposition `nat = nat * nat` is *independent* of Coq's logic.

If you really need the fact that you mentioned, then you need to assert the excluded middle as an axiom (`Axiom classical : forall P, P \/ ~ P.`), which will allow you to produce proofs of `\/` without having an explicit proof of either side and to reason by cases. Then you would be able to proof your example theorem with something like

```
intros a b. destruct (classical (a = b)).
  left. assumption.
  right. assumption.
```

Hope this helps.